# Logcat only produce FA logs

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

I am working my own android project for a long time. Until today, everything was working so fine but today suprisingly I only get

03-07 17:14:51.748 20484-14871/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC:

```
03-07 17:17:12.856 20484-15950/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Scheduling task with Gcm. Time2122773
03-07 17:17:12.869 20484-15950/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Background event processing time, ms: 104
03-07 17:17:13.892 15705-15939/-- D/FA: Logging event (FE): ad_impression(_ai), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=am, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=--, ad_event_id(_aeid)=--}]
```

and so on...

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.d("log", "log");
```

and this is my MainActivity which is working at first. I put a Log to test logcat but I cant see any log in logcat. Did anyone have something like this?

Comment: Any solution? I am only getting VFA logs currently. So weird

Answer (score 3, accepted):

/FA indicates these are FirebaseAnalytics messages. Firebase tries to do a lot automatically for you, and that includes some recommended logging. I suspect you recently added the Firebase and the related plugin to your app.

You customize this logging if you like. Maybe you just want to turn it off? Anyway, it doesn't appear anything is wrong that you need to worry about.

Documentation for customizing the FA logs are: https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events